# Searching through panel-group header

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, panel

I´m trying to create a search engine to search through my generated panel-group, but I didn´t get the correct selector done.

The generated Markup looks like this:

```
<div id="output">
<div class="panel-group">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div>
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#1">test<span class="status">Enabled</span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="panel-group">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div>
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#2">Cookie<span class="status">Enabled</span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

And so on...

Then I´ve created an input field

```
<input id="input_search" type="text" class="input-md">
```

And my JS Code

```
$j("#input_search").on('keyup', function(){
    console.log("keyUp");
    $j.each("#output .panel-group", function(i, val){
       console.log(val);
    });
    $j("#output").each(".panel-group .panel .panel-heading", function (i, val){

    });
});
```

The problem I have is that I don´t know how to build the selector. I tried to access the output div and then set the start point of at each .panel-heading, but I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in #output .panel-group
```

Can someone pls help me build the selector? How to access so much child elements?

For clarification I want to type in t and then only the panel with the heading test is displayed. The "span" which is also included in the header SHOULD NOT be included in the search result.

Here´s a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/78znm4t3/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your are using `$j.each` in wrong way. `$j.each` works on arrays but not selectors.`$j('').each` works on selectors. I made a fiddle for you [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3yt5u5pp/)

you can use `$j('some_selector').find('child_selector')` to get child elements

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, they way you build the selector and used in each is not correct. Modify your script section to

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict(true);
$j(document).ready(function () {

});
$j("#input_search").on('keyup', function(){
    console.log("keyUp");
    $j("#output .panel-group").each(function(i){
       console.log($j(this).text().trim());
    });
    $j("#output .panel-group .panel .panel-heading").each(function (i){

    });
});
```

I tried in your jsfiddle it works.